# jquery - Get multidimensional array form input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I have a search form that have multiple input types and I would like to get the values from the search form whenever user make a changes on the input.

The form is like this:

```
<form id="search">
<input type="hidden" name="cat[0][name]" value="cat1">
//select type input.
<select id="cat-0" name="cat[0][id]" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>    
<input type="hidden" name="cat[1][name]" value="cat2">
<select id="cat-1" name="cat[1][id]" >
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

//checkbox type input
<input type="hidden" name="cat[2][name]" value="cat3">
<label><input id="cat-2" type="checkbox" name="cat[2][id][]" value="1"> 1</label>
<label><input id="cat-2" type="checkbox" name="cat[2][id][]" value="2"> 2</label>
<label><input id="cat-2" type="checkbox" name="cat[2][id][]" value="3"> 3</label>


//radio type input
<input type="hidden" name="cat[3][name]" value="cat4">
<label><input id="cat-3" type="radio"  name="cat[3][id]" value="1"> 1</label>
<label><input id="cat-3" type="radio"  name="cat[3][id]" value="2"> 2</label>
<label><input id="cat-3" type="radio"  name="cat[3][id]" value="3"> 3</label>
</form>
```

As you can see the input values are in multidimensional array. How do i get those values by javascript when user make a changes on either one of the input. All I wanted to do is create a search engine like this [site](http://sms.me/) .

The form is generated dynamically, thus I can't defined a fixed id/class for every field.

The js script should be something like this?

```
$('[id^=cat]').live('change', function(e) {
            passing_data();
            return false;
        });

        function passing_data() {
            var getdata = $(':input[name="cat"]').val();//this i can't get it.
            alert(getdata);
            return false;
        }
```

The passing_data() is the part i didn't get it, it will be used in ajax to perform search function.

Any idea?

Comment: can't you simply `serialize the form` and send to server via `ajax` and handle it all there ?

Comment: Seem reasonable. Will give it a try, and give a feedback here. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try passing "this" into the function:

```
    $('[id^=cat]').live('change', function(e) {
        passing_data($(this)); // pass object as a jQuery object
        return false;
    });

    function passing_data($obj) {
        var getdata = $obj.val();
        alert(getdata);
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers that given by legendinmaking and JohnMarkT, both can solve my problem. Really appreciate yours answers. It helps me a lot.

The final solution for me is combine those two answers, like this:

```
$('[id^=cat]').live('change', function(e) {
        passing_data($(this)); // pass object as a jQuery object
        return false;
    });

    function passing_data($obj) {
        var getdata = $obj.closest("form").serialize();// i have multiple form,so it should choose the responding form.
        alert(getdata);
        return false;
    }
```